# Youtube trends v3 by age and gender like in Youtube dashboard

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to get youtube trends by age and gender as seen in the youtube trendsdashboard: [Youtube trends dashboard](https://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard)

Looking at the API and this answer SO answer [Get youtube trends v3 country wise in Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475309/get-youtube-trends-v3-country-wise-in-json), getting most popular by region seems to be provided in the API. Is there a way to break that down by age and gender?

Comment: Have you looked at the Youtube Analytics API? https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/content_owner_video_reports#demographic-reports

Comment: I took a brief look at the Analytics API and from what I saw the Analytics API is actually used to see detailed breakdown of stats about an authorized user's videos. Authorized being the keyword here. So you can only use the API to see stats about your own videos and channel. Is this an incorrect conclusion I drew?

Comment: I believe that you can only see detailed stats about your own videos or channels. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835805/does-youtube-analytics-api-just-give-you-statistics-of-your-channel

Answer (score 0):

Now you should work with Youtube Data API v3.

For most popular video

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=IN&key=API_KEY

1.part : The part names that you can include in the parameter value are id, snippet, contentDetails, fileDetails, liveStreamingDetails, localizations, player, processingDetails, recordingDetails, statistics, status, suggestions, and topicDetails.

chart :The chart parameter identifies the chart that you want to retrieve. (string) like 'mostPopular'

but how to filter with gender and age . If u have any idea get back to me